# "O nosso medo é o conseguimento com que conseguiste ser presidente da A.R."

Tags: significado, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

Um primo de Portugal mandou-me um vídeo onde ouço uma senhora a fazer um discurso.  Confesso que não entendi metade. Palavras muito estranhas. O vídeo é acompanhado de comentários onde lemos o seguinte:

> O nosso medo é o conseguimento com que conseguiste ser presidente da A.R. .............e ainda continua na A.R. a escorraçar o povo das galerias e a passear com o nosso BMW topo de gama.

Nunca ouvi a palavra "conseguimento" antes. O Piberam define como "consecução" mas, embora sabendo que refere-se ao ato de conseguir alguma coisa, essa palavra também não faz parte do meu vocabulário.  Minhas perguntas são:

1. Usa-se "conseguimento" em ptPT?
2. "O conseguimento com que conseguiste" está correto?
3. O que seria um BMW "topo de gama"?

Comment: (Eu escreveria "sabendo que se recebe". Mas talvez seja uma maneira diferente de escrever, no Brasil.)

Comment: @ANeves Você quer dizer "se refere" ?

Comment: Refere, sim, isso! (Mas se for para receber, também não me importo.)

Comment: @ANeves http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/refere-se/

Comment: @Centaurus A questão é que o "que" (ou talvez a oração subordinada desenvolvida) pede a próclise. Em Portugal, a frase como a escreveste até causa alguma estranheza que força uma pessoa a voltar atrás. As exceções da colocação do pronome que vejo para o Brasil são no sentido de _permitir_ a próclise em mais situações (como no início da frase), não de evitá-la, como fizeste.

Comment: @Artefacto Na verdade usei a enclise para evitar o que me parecia um cacófato (se refere) mas não posso afirmar que esse uso seja comum no Brasil ou que seja considerado errado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Usa-se "conseguimento" em ptPT?

Não particularmente, mas o significado é transparente porque o sufixo `-mento` é produtivo e significa processo, ação ou resultado (tal como, de resto, o sufixo "-ção"). Portanto, "conseguimento" será o processo, ação ou resultado de conseguir. Há de ser, assim, o mesmo que "consecução", essa já uma palavra mais comum. O CETEMPúblico tem 86 ocorrências do lema "consecução" e 7 de "conseguimento".

> 2. "O conseguimento com que conseguiste" está correto?

Certamente. A repetição da raiz é um jogo de palavras, não é qualquer coisa que se diria normalmente. Significa "a forma com que conseguiste". Neste contexto, o sufixo "-mento" indica processo.

> 3. O que seria um BMW "topo de gama"?

"BMW Topo de gama" significa "o melhor (ou um dos melhores) modelo na linha da automóveis da BMW". "Gama" tem aqui o [significado 3. do Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/gama): "Conjunto de coisas variadas; SÉRIE: *O vendedor ofereceu uma gama de opções.*"

Podes ver outros exemplos e como foram traduzidos para o inglês no [Reverso Context](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/portugais-anglais/topo+de+gama).

Já agora, suponho que a pessoa a que o comentário se refere é [Assunção Esteves](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Esteves). A forma como ela foi eleita para presidente da Assembleia da República (A.R.) não tem nada de extraordinário, mas já se sabe como são os comentários na Internet. O que houve foi uma novela completamente ridícula (mas merecida) com Fernando Nobre que antecedeu a eleição dela.

Comment: E o que seria A.R.?

Comment: @Centaurus Assembleia da República, o órgão legislativo unicameral do país.

Comment: No Brasil dizemos "topo de linha".